# When did 'virgin' start referring to non-alcoholic drinks

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage, history

Since there have been so many virginity questions here lately, I have another one.  As a former bartender-type, I often hear the term **virgin**, when relating to non-alcoholic drinks.  Unfortunately, search engines are overwhelmed by click-bait slideshows like "20 virgin drinks that will rock your world" and "25 bar terms you need to know!"

EDIT:  some additional research:

Upon having further time to research, I discovered these early usages:

[Out West - Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=wPRYAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA74&dq=%22virgin+drink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG29Xv973JAhUY5WMKHSa_B2cQ6AEIPTAC#v=onepage&q=%22virgin%20drink%22&f=false)

It refers to Mah-que-be, a

> secret brew of herbs which is supposed to fortify..against snake poison

In the [Quarterly Review of Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=6y9ZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22virgin%20drink%22&dq=%22virgin%20drink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikvPvb-L3JAhUK72MKHfDhCU8Q6AEIWzAI) , 1964

> now sweet words went to their heads like a virgin drink of spirits

Doesn't really answer my question, however

I can see a relation between a virgin (usually referring—albeit not exclusively—to young children) and non-alcoholic drinks, but I ask:

What is the history of the relationship between **virgin** and **non-alcoholic**?

Comment: It has not been adulterated with alcohol?

Comment: EVOO is non-alcoholic.

Answer (score 2):

It may be an extension of *Virgin Mary*, which is straight tomato juice (as opposed to a *Bloody Mary*, which has vodka). OED cites usages going back to the mid-1970s, under its entry for *virgin*:

> **Virgin Mary**  n.  [after **Bloody Mary** n.] `chiefly U.S.` a glass of tomato juice
>
> *1976*   W. Goldman *Magic* ii. 90   Some girl wanted a Virgin Mary. The waiter nodded.
>
> *1977*   J. Philips *Five Roads to Death* i. 11   A waitress approached the table. ‘A Virgin Mary... A Bloody Mary without the vodka.’
>
> *1981*   T. Heald *Murder at Moose Jaw* ix. 103   Crombie ordered himself a straight tomato juice with..Worcester. The Colonel did not, Bognor noted with approval, refer to the drink as ‘a Virgin Mary’.

Once a *Virgin Mary* had been established (as a pun of sorts) from *Bloody Mary*, it's not hard to imagine how, say, *virgin daiquiri* would have followed.

I don't know if the term goes back further than that.

Comment: I do appreciate the research.  According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloody_Mary_(cocktail) **bloody mary** was coined in 1921, and I am having some difficulty believing that it took 50+ years for the word 'virgin' to start appearing before it.

Comment: @USER_8675309 - I'm a bit surprised by the apparent timeline, too, but the OED is pretty good about citing _very_ early usages. (For example, in the same entry, one meaning of virgin is "Employed for the first time," and four example usages are cited; the earliest is from 1627 and the latest is from 1839. One of them cites "his virgin sword Ægysthus", from a 18th-century translation of Homer's _Odyssey_.) Maybe it took until the 1970's before society felt comfortable naming a drink after a figure so revered by the Catholic church? It might have been regarded as too much for their virgin ears.

Comment: found a reference to a virgin daiquiri in 1963 -- https://books.google.com/books?id=UWURAAAAIAAJ&q=%22virgin+daiquiri%22&dq=%22virgin+daiquiri%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFncGw973JAhUB_mMKHVjJCFAQ6AEIOjAC

Comment: @USER_8675309 - Nice bit of detective work. I like the research – and the drink.

Answer (score 2):

I think the original virgin cocktail was the Virgin Mary, created as an alternative to the Bloody Mary but without Vodka. Bloody Mary refers to Mary I of England, so I guess it made sense to name the alternative after another, gentler historical Mary.